# In Python, how does one override the behavior of a class instance typed on a line by itself

Tags: python, class, jupyter

Without print (which I believe invokes **str**()) what happens when a variable is on a line by itself.

This is a bit contrived, I know, but I ran into this in a Jupyter notebook when testing a class I'm creating and now I'm curious. I can't seem to find the right set of Google search terms to find the answer in the docs.

I defined a class thusly:

```
class ExceptionList(BaseException):
    pass
    # I've implemented, in very standard ways, the following methods
        # __str__()
        # __getitem__()
        # __delitem__()
        # __repr__()
    # I doubt any other specifics of the class are pertinent
```

EDIT

Here is the **repr**() implementation:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "{}({})".format(self.__class__.__name__, repr(self.__exception_list))
```

P.S. I coded that method based on http://brennerm.github.io/posts/python-str-vs-repr.html

EDIT

My implementation of **repr**() causes this behavior:

```
e = ExceptionList(["Oh, no"])


e
```

> > "ExceptionList(['Oh, no'])"

So consider:

```
e1 = Exception("Oh no!")
e2 = ExceptionList("Oh no!")
```

In separate notebook cells:

```
e1
```

> > Exception('Oh no!')

```
e2
```

> > __main__.ExceptionList()

Incidentally (maybe?) the output of:

```
e2.__class__
```

is close:

> > __main__.ExceptionList

Does it just have something to do with the scope in which the class was defined? Is it some special behavior of builtins?

Is this behavior this result of invoking some **method** that I'm unaware of? I tried implementing all of the methods produced with `dir()` though I'm willing to bet that's not exhaustive.

It probably doesn't matter for my implementation but now I **need** to know!

Boilerplate Hater Deterrent:

- I don't know anything.
- I'm a terrible programmer.
- "I thought a python was a snake..."
- I'm barely qualified to use a toaster.
- Please forgive this post's pathetic usage of SO disk space.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. ExceptionList produces the same output as Exception in Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Presumably you have defined `__repr__` to output `"__main__.ExceptionList()"`, since that is the method that does this.

Comment: Well, not exactly. Check out my edit above. __repr__() prints out the string representation of the instance such that eval() can be used to recreate it.

Comment: No. `__repr__` **is** the method that is responsible for producing the output when you type the instance on its own. Obviously when you do that you get the output you describe, because **that is what you defined `__repr__` to do**.

Comment: That's not true. I also have arguments to the class in the output of /__repr__(). The class holds a list and the repr of that list is inside the parentheses of ExceptionList. Also, my implementation of repr doesn't have /__main__ prepended.

Answer (score 0):

If the sole content of a line is a variable or object, then that line is evaluated and the variable or object is returned and not stored to a variable.

```
a = 5 + 2  # 5+2 is evaluated and stored in a
5 + 2 # 5+2 is evaluated
a # a is evaluated

class SomeCustomClass:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass

scc = SomeCustomClass()
scc # returns a reference to this instance, but ref is not stored
```

Many python interfaces like Jupyter, IPython, IDLE will display the evaluation of the line.

```
>>> 5+2
7
>>> a=5+2
[Nothing]
>>> a
7
>>> scc
<__main__.SomeCustomClass instance at 0x7fb6d5943d40>
```

The `<__main__.SomeCustomClass instance at 0x7fb6d5943d40>` is called a representation of the class. If you look at [Python's Data Model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) you will see that this representation is specified by the object's `__repr__` method.

Modifying `SomeCustomClass`:

```
class SomeCustomClass:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass
    def __repr__(self):
        return "SomeCustomClass repr"

>>> scc = SomeCustomClass()
>>> scc
SomeCustomClass repr
>>> s = str(scc) #implicit call to __repr__
>>> s
SomeCustomClass repr
```

Now adding `__str__` method:

```
class SomeCustomClass:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass
    def __repr__(self):
        return "SomeCustomClass repr"
    def __str__(self):
        return "SomeCustomClass str"

>>> scc = SomeCustomClass()
>>> scc
SomeCustomClass repr
>>> s = str(scc) #explicit call to __str__
>>> s
SomeCustomClass str
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's what method is used to "evaluate" the class instance that I'm after.